# Prime number generator in lisp

Tags: primes, lisp, common-lisp

My implementation is based on the [incremental prime sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Incremental_sieve) described on Wikipedia. I'm relatively new to lisp so I would appreciate any comments on my coding style or on the algorithm.

The below code implements a min-heap and uses it in the prime number generation algorithm:

```
(defstruct heap
  ; (cmp x y) should return true if x is less than y.
  (cmp '())
  (arr '())
  (size 0))


(defun resize (heap)
  (let* ((old-arr (heap-arr heap))
         (old-cap (length old-arr))
         (new-cap (max 10 (* 2 old-cap)))
         (new-arr (make-array (list new-cap))))
    (loop for i from 0 to (- old-cap 1)
          do (setf (aref new-arr i) (aref old-arr i)))
    (setf (heap-arr heap) new-arr)))


(defun insert (x heap)
  (let ((size (heap-size heap))
        (cmp (heap-cmp heap)))
    (when (= size (length (heap-arr heap)))
      (resize heap))
    (setf (aref (heap-arr heap) size) x)
    (setf (heap-size heap) (+ 1 size))
    (loop with arr = (heap-arr heap)
          for i = size then parent
          for parent = (floor (- i 1) 2)
          while (and (> i 0)
                     (funcall cmp x (aref arr parent)))
          do (setf (aref arr i) (aref arr parent))
             (setf (aref arr parent) x))))


(defun peek (heap)
  (aref (heap-arr heap) 0))


(defun extract (heap)
  (let* ((arr (heap-arr heap))
         (cmp (heap-cmp heap))
         (size (heap-size heap))
         (x (aref arr 0)))
    (setf (heap-size heap) (- size 1))
    (when (> size 1)
      (setf (aref arr 0) (aref arr (- size 1)))
      (loop for i = 0 then small-child-idx
            for child1-idx = (+ 1 (* 2 i))
            and child2-idx = (+ 2 (* 2 i))
            for small-child-idx = (if (and (< child2-idx (heap-size heap))
                                           (funcall cmp (aref arr child2-idx)
                                                        (aref arr child1-idx)))
                                    child2-idx
                                    child1-idx)
            while (and (< child1-idx (heap-size heap))
                       (funcall cmp (aref arr small-child-idx) (aref arr i)))
            do (let ((tmp (aref arr i)))
                 (setf (aref arr i) (aref arr small-child-idx))
                 (setf (aref arr small-child-idx) tmp))))
    x))


(defun primes ()
  (format t "3~%")
  (loop with multiples = (make-heap :cmp (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y))))
        initially (insert '(9 . 3) multiples)
        for n from 5 by 2
        if (< n (car (peek multiples)))
          do (format t "~d~%" n)
             (insert (cons (* n n) n) multiples)
        else
          do (loop while (= n (car (peek multiples)))
                   do (let* ((pair (extract multiples))
                             (m (car pair))
                             (p (cdr pair)))
                        (insert (cons (+ m (* 2 p)) p) multiples)))))


(primes)
```

Comment: Nit: `1-` and `1+` exist.